# Can't add VBA add in to SSIS

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I am trying to add in ActiveX data objects to an SSIS vb script. What am I missing here? Is it just not supported? Is it possible that the other references are interfering with my ability to add a simple reference?[image: Can't add vba]

Comment: Never tried it but I assume you have a very specific purpose for adding this?

Comment: Yes. The Microsoft documentation stated I needed it for using ado objects.  I was able to get it working without it though, but I would still like to know why the VBA extension didn't work.